# Tax Calculation for Liquidity Pool Transactions: Cost Basis Method and Procedures

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency

I've been encountering difficulties in calculating taxes on transactions related to liquidity pools. Despite using Coinledger, I've found it doesn't support multiple transactions within a liquidity pool. Consequently, I'm seeking clarity on the cost basis method typically employed for liquidity pools. Is it the average cost basis method?

Moreover, I'm curious about the procedures for determining the cost basis for various liquidity pool transactions such as "Add Liquidity," "Increase Liquidity," "Decrease Liquidity," and "Remove Liquidity." Could someone elucidate these processes?

Lastly, has anyone successfully utilized a tax platform specifically tailored for handling liquidity pool transactions? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What country taxes are you asking about?

Comment: @littleadv, the United States taxes.